# What's the correct way to write comments in attributes such as 'style' and 'onclick'?

Tags: javascript, html, css, comments

The right way to write comments in HTML is: `<!-- Comment -->`. For Javascript, the right way to write comments is `// Comment` or `/* Comment */`, while for CSS, comments are written as `/* Comment */`.

What is the right way to write comments in `style` and `onclick` attributes of HTML elements?

---

For example, which is right? This:

```
<span style='color: red; <!-- background-color: green; -->'>Test</span>
```

Or this:

```
<span style='color: red; /* background-color: green; */'>Test</span>
```

Tested in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4JHZ/1/), both codes produced the same result of the word "Test" with a red color and no background color.

---

Also, which is correct? This:

```
<span onclick="alert('1'); // alert('2');">Click me!</span>
```

this:

```
<span onclick="alert('1'); /* alert('2'); */">Click me!</span>
```

Or this:

```
<span onclick="alert('1'); <!-- alert('2'); -->">Click me!</span>
```

Because, according to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/A4JHZ/2/) fiddle, all 3 elements produce an alert saying "1" when clicked.

I would appreciate your answer.

Comment: **tl;dr;** Use the comment style of the "language" the attribute value is evaluated as.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of the `style` attribute is essentially the same as CSS files. So the comment syntax is the same as in CSS, which is `/* ... */`

The syntax of `onEVENT` attributes is Javascript. Javascript has two types of comments: `//` that comments until the end of the line, and `/* ... */` that encloses comments. If the `onEVENT` attribute is a single line, if you use `//` it will comment the rest of the attribute. If you want to end the comment earlier, use `/* ... */`. You can also have newlines in an `onEVENT` attribute; then the `//` comment will only last to the newline.

Example:

```
<div id="foo" onclick="alert('foo'); // comment */; alert('bar');">
    // comment
</div>
<div id="bar" onclick="alert('foo'); /* comment */ alert('bar');">
    /* */ comment
</div>
<div id="foobar" onclick="alert('foo'); // comment
alert('bar')">
    // comment multi-line
</div>
```

In `// comment`, the second `alert()` is commented out. In `/* */ comment`, both alerts execute. Also, both alerts execute in `// comment multi-line`.
Amazingly, the SO code highlighter gets this right!

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/YDcLG/8/)

Comment: Note that using the HTML comment syntax in `onclick` will fail validation - apparently the HTML validator checks the syntax of JavaScript event attribute values. It does not bother checking the syntax of inline style attributes, however, so even if you used an HTML comment, resulting in invalid CSS, it's still valid HTML.

Comment: Note multi–line values are allowed in HTML attribtues, including script, so `//` doesn't necessarily mark *all* following code as a comment. :-)

Comment: @RobG You need to refresh, I updated my answer to include that.

Comment: @BoltClock Sounds like a bug in the validator to me.

Comment: @Barmar: Interestingly, it only affects the HTML validator. The XHTML validator throws a huge fit in both cases.

Comment: @BoltClock - I take it by "HTML" you mean "HTML5"? Using a HTML4 Transitional doctype will also cause the validator to barf. I suspect this is another HTML5-specific change to the validation rules, in the same vein as [the more liberal stance on encoding ampersands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441750/do-ampersands-still-need-to-be-encoded-in-urls-in-html5).

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: I tried the snippets given in the question with both HTML 4 strict and transitional doctypes and neither of them seemed to have any problems with HTML comments in style attributes.

Comment: @BoltClock - Well damn, you're right. I coulda sworn it barfed at me before... I must have had another error I didn't notice.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't confuse HTML, CSS and JavaScript comments. They are not interchangeable.

Let's start with your first HTML snippet:

```
<span style='color: red; <!-- background-color: green; -->'>Test</span>
```

There is no comment here. You cannot put HTML comments in attributes. For example, if you change that attribute from being `style` to being `title`, you'll notice that the entire attribute - "comment" and all - ends up in the hover/tooltip text: http://jsfiddle.net/Mw3wy/

That means the `<!-- background-color: green; -->` content is being included in the document content - ie it's not commented out.

Next.

```
<span style='color: red; /* background-color: green; */'>Test</span>
```

Here we have nested formatting: we have an HTML element, with an attribute whose value is multiple [CSS declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css3-syntax-20030813/#declarations). In CSS, [you can create comments using `/* C-style */` block comments](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css3-syntax-20030813/#comments).

So here we have no HTML comments, but we do have CSS comments. That means the content isn't commented out from being part of the HTML document content, but it is commented out from the CSS declarations - so whatever engine is responsible for parsing the CSS and rendering elements on the page based on those declarations will ignore it.

But if we use that same syntax in a different context:

```
<span title='color: red; /* background-color: green; */'>Test</span>
```

... now there is no comment, since there is no need for CSS syntax in this snippet.

Let's talk about the next two at the same time:

```
<span onclick="alert('1'); // alert('2');">Click me!</span>  
<span onclick="alert('1'); /* alert('2'); */">Click me!</span>
```

These both have no HTML comments, but they do contain JavaScript comments. Again, we have nested formats: we have an HTML element with one attribute which is interpreted (and formatted) as JavaScript code, so you can use JavaScript-style commenting within that context.

This, however...

```
<span onclick="alert('1'); <!-- alert('2'); -->">Click me!</span>
```

... is a syntax error for your JavaScript. You might get that `alert('1')` to work, but any further code which comes after it won't execute: http://jsfiddle.net/Ma9Tb/

That's because you're using HTML comments in a context where they can't be used. You can't use HTML comments within a `<script>` element either: http://jsfiddle.net/SbZ2m/

So the important thing is to keep track of when you have nested formatting. For example, you could have an HTML attribute which contains JavaScript code - including a comment - which then manipulates a string of CSS formatted data - which includes a CSS comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EGK5X/

```
<button onclick="this.setAttribute('style', 'color:red;/*CSS comment!*/background:black;'); // JavaScript comment!">Click on me!</button>
```

If you confuse this, you'll end up with problems like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858609/css-selector-driving-me-nuts/2858857#2858857).

Answer (score -2):

I tried following code successfully -

```
    <div style="width:816px; /*height:1300px;*/ float: left"></div>
<div style="width:816px; <!--height:1300px;--> float: left"></div>
```

I think both are right ways.